# law of Demeter in ABAP

Tags: abap, law-of-demeter

i want to detect and solve the violations of the Law of Demeter in　ＡＢＡＰ．

the focus is on the classe level.
Dose anyone have some idea or articles?

please reply

best regards
yinxiao

Comment: When you say 'solve the violations' are you talking about automatically rewriting the classes ?

Comment: yes, that is only a idea, i know it is difficult to solve the problem, but i want to try it. please help.

Comment: I don't think that this question provides nearly enough evidence of even a trial implementation to qualify as programming-related.  OP should read the SO FAQ and study some of the questions which get good answers then reformulate this question.  As it stands, not a good fit to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

this is what you will need to use ( and more ):

- `READ REPORT <prog> INTO <itab>.` This will read code into an internal table for analysis
- `SYNTAX-CHECK FOR <prog> MESSAGE <m> LINE <l> WORD <w> PROGRAM <itab>.` This will syntax check any changes you make to code
- `CALL FUNCTION 'RS_DELETE_PROGRAM'` Before saving a changed report, you might have to delete it first
- `INSERT REPORT p_abap FROM it_prog.` This will create the changed report from a changed itab
- `GENERATE REPORT p_abap.` This will generate the report you inserted
- Analysis of the table `TRDIR`, for class name `XYZ` you will find in it all components with the names `XYZ========<componentname>`, these are all reports that you can read and modify
- I would also look into how SAP does 'where used', it might help you to find violations in an easy fashion

A word to the wise : there is no way that SAP will support this; 80% of these keywords are reserved for internal use only ( those keywords are of course the most interesting ;), if this is not an academic exercise, then you are almost certainly wasting your time.

Also, I am not sure that code that complies to Demeter's law is necessarily better code, but that's a philosophical discussion best had with beer.

T.